# How can I position 2 calendars next to each other instead of under each other?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I wish to position the calendars next to each other instead of under each other but when trying to drag the calendars they are not moving. Does anyone have any idea what can I do if it is possible. Thanks

This is my code( i am using visual studio 2010)

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm2.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication9.WebForm2" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <asp:Calendar ID="Calendar2" runat="server"></asp:Calendar>
    <asp:Calendar ID="Calendar1" runat="server"></asp:Calendar>
    <p>
    </p>
</asp:Content>
```

[image: calendar positions]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Insert your dates into a div, and style that div to give it the position you want. A quick sketch I did, and it works nicely:

```
<div id="date1"> 
    <asp:Calendar ID="Calendar2" runat="server"></asp:Calendar>
</div>
<div id="date2" style="position: relative; left: 300px; margin-top: -163px;">
    <asp:Calendar ID="Calendar1" runat="server"></asp:Calendar>
</div>
```

Comment: .inline{ display: inline; } style make this as simple. thanks for asking question mickespiteri

Answer (score 4):

The reason the calendars appear in vertical order is because the rendered ASP.NET markup uses a `<table>`, which by default is a block element (some more info about element layout available [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html) and [here](http://www.webdesignfromscratch.com/html-css/css-block-and-inline/)).  There are two ways to approach this:

1. Make the element not use block layout.  You can override this using the CSS property `display:inline;`, e.g.:

   ```
   <head runat="server">
   <style type="text/css">
       .inline{ display: inline; }
   </style>
   </head>
   <body>
   <form id="form1" runat="server">
   <div>
       <asp:Calendar ID="Calendar1" runat="server" CssClass="inline" />
       <asp:Calendar ID="Calendar2" runat="server" CssClass="inline" />
   </div>
   </form>
   ```
2. Wrap the containing element containing these calendar controls with positioning such that they will line up.  For an example of this, refer to Ryan Sammut's answer.

Comment: Thanks Jimmy,. Its very easy to fix comparing with selected answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use a [Table](http://weblogs.asp.net/nannettethacker/archive/2008/01/24/html-tables-to-asp-net-table-controls.aspx) and arrange the two calenders in a single row in two columns.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code to adjust with left position:

```
<div id="date1" style="position: absolute; left: 370px; margin-top:;">
    <asp:calendar id="Calendar1" runat="server" Visible="true" >/asp:calendar>
</div>

<div id="date2" style="position: absolute; left: 100px;">
    <asp:calendar id="Calendar1" runat="server" Visible="true" >          
    </asp:calendar>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

THIS CODE!!!

```
   <div id="date1" style="position: absolute; left: 370px; ">
                   <asp:calendar id="Calendar1" runat="server" Visible="true" > 

  </asp:calendar>
 </div>

 <div id="date2" style="position: absolute; left: 100px; ">
    <asp:calendar id="Calendar2" runat="server" Visible="true">  

  </asp:calendar>
  </div>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO and thanks for your help. Answers that are just code are considered low quality. It would help us more if you could explain how your answer helps solve the OP's problems.